# How to convert a midi file to array in Swift using Audiokit?

Tags: swift, audiokit

Is there any way to convert a MIDI file into an array of Note objects using AudioKit(Assuming only 1 track in the file)?

```
struct Note {
    var name: String = ""
    var distance: Float = 0.0
    var frequency: Float = 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with `MIDINoteData` of the `MusicTrackManager` class. You will need to make use of `AppleSequencer` to load the MIDI file and get the midi data as an array of note data via

`var noteArray = track.getMIDINoteData()`